# Install Spring through maven

Tags: spring, maven, ant

I am new in using maven, I am having a java class as follow:

```
 import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
 import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

 public class DecoupledDataReaderClient {
   private IReader reader = null;
   private ApplicationContext ctx = null;

   public DecoupledDataReaderClient() {
     ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("basics-reader-beans.xml");
   }

   private String fetchData() {
     reader = (IReader) ctx.getBean("reader");
     return reader.read();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     DecoupledDataReaderClient client = new DecoupledDataReaderClient();
     System.out.println("Example 1.3: Got data: " + client.fetchData());
   }
 }
```

I am having an ant built file as follow:

```
 <target name="init">
    <artifact:dependencies pathId="dependency.classpath">
        <dependency
            groupId="org.springframework"
            artifactId="spring-context"
            version="3.2.1.RELEASE"
        />
    </artifact:dependencies>    
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init">  
    <mkdir dir="classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${dest}" includeantruntime="false">

    </javac>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar}" basedir="${dest}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="src.DecoupledDataReaderClient"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="${jar}" fork="true"/>
</target>
```

When I run the ant built file I get the error:

```
     error: package org.springframework.context does not exist
     error: package org.springframework.context.support does not exist
```

Is there anything else I have to include in my ant file to make it run?

Comment: Why do you make reference of Maven and tag your question as such, if you're then asking about how "to make [my ant file] run"?

Comment: I believe it's the maven who install the spring (or at least that's what I aimed for). Anyway I am not an expert in this field if you think it has nothing to do with maven feel free to edit the question

Comment: the script doesn't seem like maven one

Comment: [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/quick-start-maven-spring-example/) is roughly what this would look like in Maven. We are not rewriting your question since we don't yet know where to go with it. Do you want support with Ant, or do you want to convert this Ant example to a Maven one?

Comment: K so here is what I am trying to do exactly: I want to have the ant build file, Use the maven to get spring. So far I downloaded the maven jar file. Put it in my ant lib directory and added the artifact in my ant build file "xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant" The spring framework get downloaded but I can't import the packages in my java file.  Maybe I am mistaking but I don't know anyway to get the spring framework in pure ant. I guess anyway I need to use maven in ant to download the required packages.