# SPRING java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, noclassdeffounderror

It seems people have had similar problems, but on IDE's.
I am not using an IDE.

I installed Spring using a Maven dependency as you will see in my build.xml file.

**I get the following stacktrace that says org.springframework.context is not found:**

> run-decouple:
>
> > ```
> > [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
> >  [java]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
> > [java]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
> >  [java]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
> >  [java]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
> >  [java]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:488)
> >  [java]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:480)
> >  [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
> >  [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
> >  [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
> >  [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> >  [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
> >  [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
> >  [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
> > ```

```
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 [java]     ... 6 more
 [java] Exception in thread "main"
 [java] Java Result: 1
```

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>   Total time: 4 seconds

**Here is my client (java file: DecoupledDataReaderClient.java):**

```
package com.example.decouple.client;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.example.filereader.IReader;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class DecoupledDataReaderClient {
  private IReader reader = null;
  private ApplicationContext ctx = null;
  public DecoupledDataReaderClient() {
    ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
  }
  private String fetchData() {
    reader = (IReader) ctx.getBean("reader");
    return reader.read();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DecoupledDataReaderClient client = new DecoupledDataReaderClient();
    System.out.println("Example 1.3: Got data: " + client.fetchData());
  }
}
```

**Here is my build.xml file with the spring dependency & classpath and xmlns to use MAVEN**
**EDIT: ADDED THE CLASSPATH TO RUN-DECOUPLE**

```
<project name="data-reader" default="compile" xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">
    <property name="src" location="."/>
    <property name="obj" location="../classes"/>
    <property name="jarfile" location="../data-reader.
        jar"/>

    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="dist" />
        <artifact:dependencies pathId="dependency.classpath">
            <dependency groupId="org.springframework"
                        artifactId="spring-context"
                        version="3.2.4.RELEASE" />
        </artifact:dependencies>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <mkdir dir="${obj}"/>
        <depend srcdir="${src}" destdir="${obj}" />
        <javac includeantruntime="false" 
               srcdir="${src}" 
               destdir="${obj}">
            <classpath refid="dependency.classpath" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <jar basedir="${obj}" destfile="${jarfile}">
            <include name="*.class"/>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="compile">
        <java classpath="${obj}" classname="VanillaDataReaderClient"/>
    </target>

    <target name="decouple-jar" depends="compile">
        <jar destfile="dist/decouple.jar" basedir="${obj}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.example.decouple.client.DecoupledDataReaderClient"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>  
    </target>

    <target name="run-decouple" depends="decouple-jar">
    <java fork="true" jar="dist/decouple.jar" >
        <classpath>
            <path refid="dependency.classpath" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>


</project>
```

**And lastly, here is my beans.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean name="reader" class="com.example.filereader.VanillaFileReader">
        <constructor-arg value="src/hello.txt" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

If someone could help me with why it is not finding the class even though the spring dependency is in my build.xml (which downloaded successfully according to the output of build.xml) and with it in the classpath, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `maven clean install`? Or with maven you only meant to download the .jar files?

Comment: Problem is in your pom.xml, its missing dependency. You need to share it.

Comment: @porfiriopartida I have not. As I mentioned, I used the "xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant" line to allow my file to use Maven's dependencies. I then used its dependencies to try and download Spring, which should have installed it, but I get the errors I mentioned when calling Spring classes

Comment: @Lokesh - Where may I find the pom.xml file and what do you mean by sharing it?

Comment: @porfiriopartida I think I understand what you mean now..  Is it that adding the dependency to my build.xml only downloaded the jar files for Spring, but did not install them?

Comment: Well you could start a maven project, add spring dependencies in the pom.xml file and then compile it using maven it will generate your .war files.

Comment: Possible related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073898/install-spring-through-maven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`artifact:dependencies` is storing the classpath for the Spring dependencies in the path `dependency.classpath`, and you're using that when you compile:

```
<javac ...
    ...
    <classpath refid="dependency.classpath" />
```

However, when you run, you're only including your compiled source in the classpath:

```
<target name="run" depends="compile">
    <java classpath="${obj}" classname="VanillaDataReaderClient"/>
</target>
```

This means the Spring classes aren't included.

Try including `dependency.classpath` as well:

```
<target name="run" depends="compile">
    <java classname="VanillaDataReaderClient">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${obj}"/>
            <path refid="dependency.classpath"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

Edit:
Your `run-decouple` target is using `jar`: "[When using the jar attribute, all classpath settings are ignored](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html)". Switch to specifying the main class and the classpath, so you can include the dependencies:

```
<target name="run-decouple" depends="decouple-jar">
    <java fork="true" classname="com.example.decouple.client.DecoupledDataReaderClient">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="dist/decouple.jar" />
            <path refid="dependency.classpath" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to run the "run-decouple" target.
The target titled "run" works just fine.

Aside from this, I have already tried including the refid in the "run-decouple" target & it was a fail as well.

Comment: If `run-decouple` depends on Spring, please try the same change there, and show the task configuration and error.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have edited the build.xml to show the classpath difference in `run-decouple` .. The error however remained exactly the same.

Comment: You're using `jar`; from [the documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) "When using the jar attribute, all classpath settings are ignored". Define a classpath of `<pathelement location="dist/decouple.jar"/>` and the `dependency.classpath`, and specify the `classname`.

Comment: Would I do `<pathelement path="dependency.classpath"/>` or do I keep the `refid`??

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those changed a thing.
Also, you cannot explicitly specify the classname when using `jar` .. This is done in `decouple-jar` with the manifest to specify the main class where my error comes from.

Comment: Don't use jar; use a classpath and a classname. Yes, use the refid.

Comment: Thank you, your edit seemed to have fixed the `noclassdeffounderror` because it's complaining about not finding my `beans.xml` file instead now.